# ADFS 3.0 and JWT token

Tags: oauth, saml, adfs

We have a ADFS server farm running version 3.0. Right now, we have it enabled to authenticate 3rd party vendor applications. We are planning to leverage this existing server farm to generate a JWT token for it to be consumed by our in-house custom applications. Does anyone know the steps to be followed for generating a JWT token which returns all the AD groups associated with the user?

Configuration - Windows Server 2012 R2, ADFS 3.0. 
Can use either OAuth or SAML.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/05/26/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-adfs/) should help.

Note that you should really use OpenID Connect for authentication but that's not available on ADFS 3.0. Also the user case for ADFS 3.0 OAuth is web API not application.

Comment: Thank you. But why exactly do we need to use openid connect? Right now with ADFS, it does generate jet token with required claims.

Comment: Yes - but technically it's not supported wrt. an application. It's supposed to be for web API only. If that's your use case, no problem.

Comment: Why does one need openid connect when ADFS provides the required token?